# Nested element in the HTML is not changing its position after resizing the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a drag and drop project in react, where I am trying to drag the texts/images/SVG from the tabs and clone it and then drop the clone onto a div. I am doing that by coneNode and specifying the x & y position of the element. As the x & y positions are static and the **div** which is the "dropZone" is a flexbox, whenever the window resizes the elements inside need to be relative to the dropZone **div**.

**Things I have tried -:**

- Make the outer div absolute and the inner divs & p-tags relative

  - Problem with this is that the inner divs & p-tags snap to the upper right-hand side
- Calculate the getBoundingClientRect() of the dropped element and then figure out the relative-X and relative-Y

  - Problem with this approach is that it aligns the item specific to the body, not the "dropZone" div

**Functionality that I want -:**

- Users should be able to click on the tabs option and drag and drop the cloned texts/images/SVG onto the drop zone. The cloned element should be inserted at the x-y position of the cursor
- User should be able to move the dropped texts/images/SVG within the drop zone

I currently have the position of the p-tag as **fixed**, I know this is not the correct approach. I have to either listen to resize events or somehow get the relative X and Y of the div? I am completely lost and any help would be great. Thank you!!

Here is the image of HTML structrue -: [HTML-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS3nz.png)

And here is the css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: black;
  height: 100% !important;
}

#root {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.App {
  height: 100% !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column !important;
}

.MuiPaper-root {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: black !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}

#dropZone {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(135, 182, 182);
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;

  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  position: relative;
}

.MuiTabs-root {
  background-color: rgb(152, 167, 126);
  margin: 5px;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}

p {
  position: fixed;
}

#data {
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

#dropDragZone {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here is a youtube video of the problem -: [link](https://youtu.be/FFC5ZgAAsZI)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not include external links. Once those links get fixed, this question will be useless to future visitors. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello @disinfor, I made the necessary changes. Thank you!!